# Select Pivot Table Columns

Tags: python

I have a pivot table like this;

```
                     amount
product year-month         
5       2015-03-01    408.0
        2015-04-01   6081.0
        2015-05-01  10915.0
        2015-06-01  12202.0
        2015-07-01  13342.0
        2015-08-01  18786.0
        2015-09-01   9491.0
        2015-10-01   6014.0
                ...
```

I can't select index columns.
How can I select column 'year-month' or 'amount'?

```
year-month         
2015-03-01   
2015-04-01  
2015-05-01  
2015-06-01
...
```

**Edit**

This doesn't work;

```
pivot_df['year-month']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One command which is very useful, especially after a pivot table command, is to reset the index:

```
pivot_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

You can also set a specific column to be an index:

```
pivot_df.set_index('year-month', inplace=True)
```